# What is a simple axiomatisation of groups using division?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra

I recall from an old exercise I did as an undergrad that groups can be axiomatised using division rather than multiplication:

A group is a non-empty set equipped with a binary division operator / satisfying some equational axioms.

I don't remember the axioms, but I do remember that $x/y = x\cdot y^{-1}$. Because $x/x = 1$ and $1/x = x^{-1}$ we can recover the group structure by setting $x\cdot y = x/(1/y)$ and so such an axiomatisation should exist.

However, I am interested in a *simple*, preferably *natural*, axiomatisation. Does anyone know one?

Also, if you know a classic reference for this result/exercise, I will be grateful.

Comment: There's something here https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/projects/gtsax/

Answer (score 1):

Set $x/x=1$ for all $x$ in $G$ and $x/1=x$, so there is a unique element $1$ and for all $x/x$ is equal to that.  $(x/(1/y))/(1/z)= x/(1/(y/(1/z))$ is clearly equivalent to the associative group law where $x/(1/y)=x*y$ . So we have associative law and the $1$ defined is certainly an identity. For inverses, you can have define $1/(1/x)=x$ so $x*1/x=1$ as desired. Perhaps there is a cleaner formulation of the associative rule though the others seem natural enough.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. It's clear that your equations hold in every group, but is any structure with a binary operation / satisfying these laws a group? For example, why is x/x = y/y for all x, y?